# TESTNG test run sequence

Tags: java, testng

I am very new in TESTNG.
I made a test method that checks successful login.
but how can I proceed after that without closing the browser i.e. using same browser.I want to run the tests in sequence i.e. after login the next test will be executed.If I add a new method in the existing class then it is not running in same browser.

```
@BeforeMethod        
public void beforeMethod() throws Exception 
{               
//setting paths from env property file              
driverPath = read_trans.getProperty("driverPath");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",driverPath+"chromedriver.exe");
driver = new ChromeDriver();     
}   


@Test           
public void check_successfull_login() throws InterruptedException
{            
String TestCaseName="L1";   
//TestCaseName = read_trans.getProperty("TestCaseName");

excel_read dp=new excel_read();
String[] credentials=dp.get_credentials(TestCaseName);

driver.manage().window().maximize();
read_trans.getProperty("URL");
//System.out.println(A);
driver.navigate().to(read_trans.getProperty("URL"));
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,5);     
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='navbar']/a")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='navbar']/div[2]/ul/a")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='pan")).sendKeys(credentials[0]);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@.....']")).sendKeys(credentials[1]);      
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn ....']")).click();


} `
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reuse `driver` across tests, you need to initialise it once before your tests and not before each test method.

You can achieve that by changing the `@BeforeMethod` annotation to `@BeforeClass`.

If you then need to make sure that the login method runs first, you can annotate the other tests as follows:

```
@Test(dependsOnMethods="check_successfull_login") public void otherTest() {}
```

Or you can put the content of the login method in the `@BeforeClass` as well.